# What is the correct way to use non persisted records on dynamic routes in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**What I am trying to do:** 
Create a record and not persist it yet, because some of the info required will be filled on the next route.

**How am I doing it?** 
I am generating a uuid, and assigning it to the record. And then transitioning to the new route.

```
createOrder() {
      var d = new Date().getTime();
      var uuid = 'xxxxyyyxxxxxxxxyyxyxxxyyy'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c){
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
      });
      console.log(uuid)
      this.get('model.event.orders').addObject(this.store.createRecord('order', {id:uuid}));

 this.transitionToRoute('orders.list.new', uuid);
```

**The problem:** 
The URL is as expected `/orders/<order:id>/new` but,
Upon transitioning the model tries to fetch the data from the server which returns in a 404, instead of using local storage or memory where the record exists.

**What I want?:**
How can I make it use the local storage so that it doesn't result in an error.

Comment: you should pass the model, not the id to `transitionToRoute`

Comment: thanks @Lux it worked !

Answer (score 1):

As Lux wrote in a comment, passing the model would fix your problem. The reason is simple: if a model is given as argument in the [transitionToRoute](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Controller/methods/transitionToRoute?anchor=transitionToRoute) function, Ember would use that model instead of fetching the model from the backend (by calling the `model hook`).

From the docs:

> Optionally supply a model for the route in question. The model will be serialized into the URL using the serialize hook of the route.
>
> If a literal is passed (such as a number or a string), it will be treated as an identifier instead. In this case, the `model hook` of the route will be triggered

Answer (score 0):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').peekRecord('order', params.id);
  }
});
```

This is also an ember way of making sure that ajax request is not fired.
It will make request directly to ember store.